# Built-in functions not working with evaluated strings, why?

Tags: css, string, less, evaluation

It seems that evaluated color strings are not working with some built-in LESS functions.
I have tried using `e()` and `~""` and any combination of both.

I might find a workaround for my particular case, I’m just asking if this is this expected behaviour, or if there is a fault in my reasoning? Any insight appreciated.

For example here, the color is created from an evaluated string; note the 'missing' `#` in the hex value that gets added later :

```
.broken-mixin(@hexcode: '9719e1') {

    @color: e("#@{hexcode}");

    // this works as expected
    background-color: @color;

    // this does work too
    .very-simple-mixin(@color);

    // Undefined_methodError: error evaluating function `fade`: 
    // Object #<Object> has no method 'toHSL'
    background-color: fade(@color,30%);

    // SyntaxError: error evaluating function `red`: 
    // Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    background-color: rgba(red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), 0.5);

}
```

Otherwise built-in functions work normally work with variables in mixins, for example :

```
.mixin-works(@myColor: #00ff00) {
    // works just fine
    background-color: fade(@myColor,30%);
    // or this, works too
    background-color: rgba(red(@myColor), green(@myColor), blue(@myColor), 0.5);
}
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Converting the evaluated string into a `color` object like `background-color: fade(color("@{color}"),30%);` would work. I think this is because the `fade` function requires a color object as input instead of a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Quoting the [LESS website's Function Reference](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-fade):**

> **fade**
>
> Set the absolute transparency of a color. Can be applied to colors whether they already have an opacity value or not.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> color: A color object.
>
> amount: A percentage 0-100%.

The `fade` function requires a `color` object as input to it and hence passing an evaluated string as a parameter to the function doesn't work.

It can be solved by using the built-in [`color`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-color) function which converts a string into an equivalent `color` object like below:

```
background-color: fade(color("@{color}"),30%);
```

The other built-in functions also are not working for the same reason (that is, they expect a `color` object as an input).

> **red:**
>
> Extracts the red channel of a color object.
>
> **Parameters:** color - a color object.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was blind but you made me see. I guess an error like `"fade() function expects Color object as parameter, String object was passed"` would have been informative. Anyway, I’ll read that documentation! Great answer and extremely fast :)

Comment: @gabssnake: Happy to help mate. Yes, I too feel that sometimes the error messages could be more informative but then there must be a good reason why such an error message isn't provided because if it was simple then the LESS core team would have probably done that already.