# Less css compiler. Unable to use darken property

Tags: css, less

I'm developing a project using LESS as compiler for my CSS.
I have already a fully working loop that sets the background color properly.

My question is this:
With my current code, when i try to use darken property, the compiling result is this:

> SyntaxError:error evaluating function `darken`: Object # has
>   no method 'toHSL'

and the code is this one:

```
@colors:
"008B8B",
"00CDCD",
"00EEEE";

/* Colors and background loop (based on colors.less arrays) */
.loop-colors(@index) when (@index > 0){ // loop to generate rules for each color
  .loop-colors(@index - 1);// call for the next iteration
  @color: e(extract(@colors, @index));
  @hexColor:  ~'#@{color}';
  @border: 1px solid darken(@hexColor, 5%);
  &.col-@{color}{
    background: @hexColor;
    border:@border;
  }
}
```

i have no idea why this is not good.

I mean, i think is because the list of color doesn't have the "#" before every color, but just because i'm using it on the css class as well, i can't add it to @colors, so i have to add it later.

I don't know if and why adding the "#" later will affect the darken property and how.

Thanks

Comment: `~'#@{color}'` creates a string value not a color. To create a color object (expected by color functions) from a string use `color` function, e.g. `color('#@{color}')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546248/less-built-in-functions-not-working-with-evaluated-strings-why/25546518#25546518

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @seven-phases-max, `~'#@{color}'` will not create a color but a string. To convert a string to a color, you can use [**color**](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-color) function.

```
@colors:
  "008B8B",
  "00CDCD",
  "00EEEE";

/* Colors and background loop (based on colors.less arrays) */
.loop-colors(@index) when (@index > 0) { // loop to generate rules for each color
  .loop-colors(@index - 1);// call for the next iteration
  @color: e(extract(@colors, @index));
  @hexColor:  ~'#@{color}';
  @border: 1px solid darken(color(@hexColor), 5%);
  &.col-@{color} {
    background: @hexColor;
    border: @border;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now i have this error when i try to compile:

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory

Any suggestion on how to solve? Thanks

Comment: @lam It seems that a bug of your Less builder is triggered by your Less code. There must be an infinite loop, which won't break when building some special code. After some Googling, I found a probably helpful [discussion](https://github.com/twitter/recess/issues/22). By the way, you can add another question about this problem on StackOverflow.