# Less css, unable to compile properly

Tags: css, less

i'm trying to compile a less file into css, but when i try to compile this code here:

```
.colors() {
  .-("Maroon",#800000);
.-("Red",#FF0000);
.-("Orange",#FFA500);
.-("Yellow",#FFFF00);
.-("Olive",#808000);
.-("Green",#800000);
.-("Purple",#800080);
.-("Fuchsia",#FF00FF);
.-("Lime",#00FF00);
.-("Teal",#008080);
}


.icons(){
  .-("icon-adjust", "\f042");
  .-("icon-adn", "\f170");
  .-("icon-align-center", "\f037");
  .-("icon-align-justify", "\f039");
  .-("icon-align-left", "\f036");
  .-("icon-align-right", "\f038");
  .-("icon-ambulance", "\f0f9");
  .-("icon-anchor", "\f13d");
  .-("icon-android", "\f17b");
  .-("icon-angellist", "\f209");
  .-("icon-angle-double-down", "\f103");
  .-("icon-angle-double-left", "\f100");
  .-("icon-angle-double-right", "\f101");
}

.easyUI {
  .colors();
  .-(@color_,@bgColor)
{@color: e(@color_);
&.@{color} {
  background: @bgColor;
  color: contrast(@bgColor);
  border: 1px solid darken(@bgColor, 20%);
  &:hover {
    background: darken(@bgColor, 8%);
    border: 1px solid darken(@bgColor, 15%);
  }
}
}
.icons();
.-(@icon_,@content)
{@icon: e(extractor(@icon_));
&.@{icon} {
  &.prepend:before {
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    content: @content;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  &.append:after {
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    content: @content;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
}
}
```

It fails and i get this error:

> SyntaxError:error evaluating function `darken`: Object # has
>   no method 'toHSL'

why? any explanation about this?

thanks a lot

Comment: use  `darken(color(@bgColor), 8%);`

Comment: with your suggestion i have another error, this one: `color`: argument must be a string

Comment: `darken(color(~"@{bgColor}), 8%);` see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079859/less-css-compiler-unable-to-use-darken-property

Comment: It is supposed you should not call `.icons()` in the same scope as `.colors()` (or if you do, you need to use some more unique mixin names instead of `.-`). The problem is that since both `colors` and `icons` code use the same `.-`  for their callbacks, both are stacked so the one defined with for `icons` is also invoked for `colors`, hence `@bgColor` there also gets icon character values and thus the error.

Comment: Basically you need to separate them like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/db019e14f530c0a34bd4#file-26538514-less) (or use some other name instead of `.-`). (I also had to fix/clean-up other things, like `extractor`?! :)

Comment: Btw. and if by some chance you're using Less v2 you also won't need quotes for colors (i.e. quotes and `@color: e(@color_);` becomes unnecessary, see code for icons).